Is there a tool on the web where I can simply copy-paste a LaTex expression and see the symbolic expression?
My earlier question was closed as off-topic, but this is a real question.
I do not know Latex.
In an online course, I see this:

Choosing the mean of the smallest and largest element of an array of
n elements  will always lead to perfectly balanced partition with at
least $$\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ elements in each partition.

Is there a (free) tool on the web where I can simply copy-paste that expression and see the symbolic expression? I have searched but did not see any except pasting into Edge-CoPilot which shows:


Have you tried the VS Code markdown? https://i.sstatic.net/f5HzBCS6.png

https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0ALaTeX:%20%5Cfmtversion%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D But note that the code is probably intended to be rendered by your browser using mathml, mathjax or something. LaTeX renders complete documents and $$ shouldn't be used. I'm afraid that means this question is also off-topic. I don't know how that expression is supposed to render. My guess is it is just erroneous regardless of markup language.

If I understand your question well then the answer to this question is included in the question itself and in the inserted image. It says that there is small typo (I accept that you don't know what typo: the single $ must be at both sides, no $$). The image shows the result of TeX rendering too. What do you need to know more? (If you don't want to deal with TeX).

In fact, if the input includes / instead \over (or in LaTeX \frac) then the rendered output is simply ⌊/2⌋.

The statement is mathematically completely wrong.

This question is similar to: Compiling documents online. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See the section Tiny equation compiler in the accepted answer of the duplicate. I personally like https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php from that list (2nd item).

@Stephen If I understood you correctly, I should create a .md file in VSC and copy-paste the expression and it will display the symbols? That will be the easiest to do.

@Stephen how did you bring up the side-by-side preview? CTRL+K V did not work for me. I have VSC 1.94 Is Markdown the same as LateX? VSC help page is here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#:~:text=Tip%3A%20You%20can%20also%20right,command%20(Ctrl%2BK%20V).

@Marijn I copy-pasted into the text box for Tiny equation compiler. Now what? There is no button to click to run it.

@user691586 I copy-pasted that expression from the online Coursera course. I don't know Latex, as I said.

@cfr if you can put your comment as an answer, I shall select it.

@likejudo on the page from the url that I posted (https://editor.codecogs.com/) you can indeed copy-paste in the text box, the code will be run automatically. You see the symbolic expression in the grey box below the input box and you can download it in various formats or hotlink the url with the equation in it. With copy-pasting however you might need to trigger the automatic compilation by typing an extra space or something in the box and removing it again, it seems that the automatic detection that something has changed in the text box doesn't always trigger on copy-paste.

@likejudo I can't answer a closed question.

@cfr I don't know why they close the questions - this is a real-world question. If it is off-topic then they should amend the rules to allow it - or point out where it should be asked.

@likejudo it's off-topic here because it is really about a different technology not based on TeX. while this particular formula may render in the same way (once corrected), that's not true in general. so pasting arbitrary formulae like this into a LaTeX compiler won't necessarily produce the correct output or, in some cases, any output at all.

@likejudo the real answer is to get your web browser to render such things. of course, if an expression is invalid, it won't render. but that's true for anything.

I agree that it is a real question - some of the solutions may be based on other technologies, but others (like texlive.net) are real LaTeX. However, I still voted to close, because I think the question is a duplicate (of the other question I linked above), and also one of the other close voters selected the duplicate reason. Does that other question not provided useful answers for you, and if not, why not?

Thanks to David Carlisle and Stefan Kottwitz, you can even try complete document compilation online with https://texlive.net/ . Here is how to use this website just for one formula :
testing page .

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730479/is-there-a-tool-on-the-web-where-i-can-simply-copy-paste-a-latex-expression-and#comment1819071_730479

I am amazed that I could save the result into MS Word and then add space to the symbols etc.

not sure whose answer to tick. @cfr or yours, since they are exactly the same

@likejudo just accept this one. I'll survive without the points :-).

@cfm or can you reopen the question?

You asked,

Is there a (free) tool on the web where I can simply copy-paste [an] expression and see [its LaTeX output]?

For reasonably simple math material, such as \lfloor n/2 \rfloor, give latex2png.com a try.

Note: The input must be all-math. I.e., do not enter $ at the start and end of the math expression.

Thanks. I am amazed that in texlive.net I could save the result into MS Word and then add space to the symbols etc.

I've used this for some time: https://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor
It's didn't worked last time I needed it, but it looks like everything okay today.
